# How to get file names in go winc gui windows library OnDropFiles event

Tags: user-interface, go, winapi, drag-and-drop

Get file names dropped on form in GO gui app based on https://github.com/tadvi/winc

- First I'm enable `mainWindow.EnableDragAcceptFiles(true)`
- After catching

  `mainWindow.OnDropFiles().Bind(func(e *winc.Event) {
    fmt.Println(mainWindow)
   })`
- How to get file names dropped on form/window?
- In winc library https://github.com/tadvi/winc/blob/master/wndproc.go
  28 str. I found function returned coordinates and filenames, but to
  which object or event_id_object must I call this function?

Comment: Hi Kvach, you can [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/).

Answer (score 1):

It's done by interface Data, like

```
mainWindow.OnDropFiles().Bind(func(e *winc.Event) {
    dropEvent:= e.Data.(*winc.DropFilesEventData)
    fmt.Println(dropEvent.Files)
})
```